# Send files(all folder) via pxssh in python

Tags: python, c, user-interface, ssh, connection

i can't find anywhere how to send files via this library, can anyone help?

```
import pxssh
import getpass
try:                                                            
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    hostname = raw_input('hostname: ')
    username = raw_input('username: ')
    password = getpass.getpass('password: ')
    s.login (hostname, username, password)
    s.sendline ('uptime')   # run a command
    s.prompt()             # match the prompt
    print s.before          # print everything before the prompt.
    s.sendline ('ls -l')
    s.prompt()
    print s.before
    s.sendline ('df')
    s.prompt()
    print s.before
    s.logout()
except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh, e:
    print "pxssh failed on login."
    print str(e)
```

Comment: what error or what problem you facing

Comment: I think there is no error in this code. I Think he wants so send a file (via scp?). I actually want to do the same.